# How to pass request params for json body in retrofit?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

How to set request params for json type params in a call from MainActivity?

This is my Interface class in which there is headers annotation of type application/json and using the post method and use call in which using body annotation having a model for param request

```
public interface ApiStorePhotoInterface {
        @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
        @POST("photo/st/v7")
        Call<PhotoStoreMainModel> getResponse(@Body ParamModel paramModel);
    }
```

Here ParamModel is json model and Use this for call.

2 Param Models for @Body in Interface-
This Model contains values with the  List in  which ParamProductDetailModel is the second model in it.
   1st Param Model -

```
public class ParamModel {

    @SerializedName("apiKey")
    @Expose
    private String apiKey;
    @SerializedName("affId")
    @Expose
    private String affId;
    @SerializedName("act")
    @Expose
    private String act;
    @SerializedName("latitude")
    @Expose
    private String latitude;
    @SerializedName("longitude")
    @Expose
    private String longitude;
    @SerializedName("devinf")
    @Expose
    private String devinf;
    @SerializedName("appver")
    @Expose
    private String appver;
    @SerializedName("productDetails")
    @Expose
    private List<ParamProductDetailModel> productDetails = null;

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apiKey) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
    }

    public String getAffId() {
        return affId;
    }

    public void setAffId(String affId) {
        this.affId = affId;
    }

    public String getAct() {
        return act;
    }

    public void setAct(String act) {
        this.act = act;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getDevinf() {
        return devinf;
    }

    public void setDevinf(String devinf) {
        this.devinf = devinf;
    }

    public String getAppver() {
        return appver;
    }

    public void setAppver(String appver) {
        this.appver = appver;
    }

    public List<ParamProductDetailModel> getProductDetails() {
        return productDetails;
    }

    public void setProductDetails(List<ParamProductDetailModel> productDetails) {
        this.productDetails = productDetails;
    }

}
```

2nd Param Model -

```
 public class ParamProductDetailModel  {

    @SerializedName("productId")
    @Expose
    private String productId;
    @SerializedName("qty")
    @Expose
    private String qty;

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(String qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

}
```

This is the client class

Client class-

This is the retrofit builder class

```
public class ApiStorePhotoClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "  https://services.something.com/api/";

    private static ApiStorePhotoInterface apiInterface;

    public static ApiStorePhotoInterface getApi() {
        if (apiInterface == null) {
            apiInterface = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()
                    .create(ApiStorePhotoInterface.class);
        }
        return apiInterface;
    }
}
```

Now, in my Main class-

```
ApiStorePhotoInterface apiInterface = ApiStorePhotoClient.getApi();

Call<PhotoStoreMainModel> call = apiInterface.getResponse("What to write here??");
```

How to send Request inside the model in getResponse()?

PhotoStoreMainModel is the response model. The code has 3 response model in which the PhotoStoreMainModel is one of them and 2 request params model which is posted above.

How to send request params in @body ParamModel inside Mainclass in getResponse()?

How to set lines for a call in my MainActivity class?

> I Expect the result but not able to hit the API due to request params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your object like this:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
   try {
     jsonObject.put("key1", "value1");
     jsonObject.put("key2", value2);

     JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

    ApiStorePhotoInterface apiInterface = ApiStorePhotoClient.getApi();

    **Call<PhotoStoreMainModel> call = apiInterface.getResponse((JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonObject.toString()));  //This is not the correct way to parse the json. Not getting correct hit** 
    
    call.enqueue(new Callback<PhotoStoreMainModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<PhotoStoreMainModel> call, Response<PhotoStoreMainModel> response) {
                 }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<PhotoStoreMainModel> call, Throwable t) {
                    call.cancel();
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I can't use this line getResponse((JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonObject.toString())); in my code as my Interface has @Body ParamModel paramModel

Comment: @AnkitGupta  Change inside your interface like  Call<PhotoStoreMainModel> getResponse(@Body JsonObject paramModel);

Comment: Why we use JsonParser?

Comment: It'll convert JSONObject to JsonObject

Comment: Not getting response in this function --public void onResponse(Call<PhotoStoreMainModel> call, Response<PhotoStoreMainModel> response) {
PhotoStoreMainModel photoStoreMainModel=response.body(); // PhotoStoreMainModel  is my Response Model
}  Is my Interface is right?

Comment: check retrofit 2 logs, so you can get ideas that your API executes properly or not.

Comment: I got this response PackageName.Models.PhotoStoreMainModel@c989874 checked in Log.i("test","test"+photoStoreMainModel);                            
PhotoStoreMainModel photoStoreMainModel=response.body();

Comment: Got this in logs for **getResponse()**  in this  Call<PhotoStoreMainModel> call = apiInterface.getResponse((JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonObject.toString())); retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall@8fc44ec

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192934/discussion-between-ankit-gupta-and-bhoomika-patel).

Comment: Hello this is my new request params --
{ 
"apikey": "wseoagbiis5dd6vq5tfbs3r1c8rsz", 
"affid": "team", 
"appver": "1.00", 
"productDetails": [{ 
"productId": "6670002", 
"imageDetails": [{ 
"qty": "2", 
"url": "http://something.com/assets_admin/uploads/frame_image/15562644967Imageteam.Jpeg" 
}, { 
"qty": "2", 
"url": "http://something.com/assets_admin/uploads/frame_image/15562733007Imageteam.Jpeg" 
}] 
}] 
}  How to add objects in imageDetails and in productDetails?

Comment: JsonObject jsonObject1=new JsonObject();jsonObject1.addProperty("apiKey", "wseoagbiis5dd6vq5tfbs3r1c8rsz"); ..
jsonObject1.addProperty("appver", "1.00");
JsonObject productDetail1 = new JsonObject();
productDetail1.addProperty("productId", "6670002");
JsonObject imageDetails = new JsonObject();
for(int i1=0;i1<imageDetails.size();i1++){
imageDetails.addProperty("qty", "2"); imageDetails.addProperty("url", "http://something.com/assets_admin/uploads/frame_image/1556273644967Imageteam.Jpeg");}JsonArray array1 = new JsonArray();array1.add(imageDetails);jsonObject1.add("imageDetails", array1)

Comment: i think you accepted that answer, so i thaught you have fixed your error.. Do you want help ?

Comment: This is my new request params and at evening I will edit your answer too and approve it.

Comment: i dont mean it, let me check your new request. i'll edit this here soon.

Comment: try this:         productDetail1.add("object",jsonObject1);

Comment: I have problem to add in imagedetails

Comment: @AnkitGupta I edited my answer. check it. It is creating same like your request params

Comment: got this error.  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference   for this line   if (photoStoreMainModel.getStatus().equals("success")) {

Comment: may be yo got null response. check it properly.

Comment: Okay I will check

Answer (score 1):

No need to add `content type`

Change your `interface`like

```
public interface ApiStorePhotoInterface {


        @POST("photo/st/v7")
        Call<PhotoStoreMainModel> getResponse(@Body JsonObject obj);
    }
```

Make `json object` like:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
json.addProperty("affId", id_value)
```

// like above all params

pass the above in object in getResponse

Comment: Call<PhotoStoreMainModel> call = apiInterface.getResponse((JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(jsonObject.toString().trim())); GIVING error

Comment: JsonObject this is not supporting. Error Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'com.google.gson.JsonElement'  but JSONObject is Supporting